# Creating a vector of fixed sized queue (boost circular queue)

Tags: c++, boost, vector, queue

I have two questions:
1. How can I create a vector of boost circular queues? 
2. How should I indicate the size of the vector for the former?

I tried the following but I get an error

```
// Boost Circular Queue -- This works fine

boost::circular_buffer<pkt> pkt_queue(3);

// Vector of queues - This has errors, i also wish to initialize the vector


std::vector<pkt_queue> per_port_pkt_queue;
```

Comment: forgot to mention pkt is a struct

Comment: `pkt_queue` is not a type but an object. It should be as simple as `std::vector<boost::circular_buffer<pkt>>...`.

Comment: Thanks Jesse, but I still have some difficulty in understanding why it should be a pkt and not pkt_queue. I wanted to create  std::vector<boost::circular_buffer<pkt_queue> > per_port_pkt_queue;

Comment: Do you know the difference between `types` and `objects`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a vector of queues:

```
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

struct pkt { int data; };

int main() {
    // Boost Circular Queue -- This works fine
    typedef boost::circular_buffer<pkt> pkt_queue;

    pkt_queue a_queue(3);

    // Vector of queues - This has errors, i also wish to initialize the vector
    std::vector<pkt_queue> per_port_pkt_queue;

    per_port_pkt_queue.emplace_back(3);
    per_port_pkt_queue.emplace_back(3);
    per_port_pkt_queue.emplace_back(3);

    // or
    per_port_pkt_queue.assign(20, pkt_queue(3)); // twenty 3-element queues
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc3000ab13f02cc7)**

Comment: Thanks, I shall try it